# Convert Numbers to Words using only SELECT CASE in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new in the environment of vb.net. So, our professor asks us to convert numbers to words using only Select Case. We are only allowed using SELECT CASE -- If, If else, arrays and such are NOT allowed. The problem is I do it in a "hard code" way and I want it to be more "clean" and efficient and maximum numbers are up to 5 digits. I hope someone can give me bright ideas on this.

```
    Dim one As String = "One"
    Dim two As String = "Two"
    Dim three As String = "Three"
    Dim four As String = "Four"
    Dim five As String = "Five"
    Dim six As String = "Six"
    Dim seven As String = "Seven"
    Dim eight As String = "Eight"
    Dim nine As String = "Nine"
    Dim ten As String = "Ten "
    Dim twenty As String = "Twenty "
    Select Case input >= 20 And input <= 99
        Case True
            Select Case input
                Case 20
                    lblOutput.Text = twenty
                Case 21
                    lblOutput.Text = twenty + one
                Case 22
                    lblOutput.Text = twenty + two
                Case 23
                    lblOutput.Text = twenty + three
```

Comment: Recursion would suffice here, are you stuck at a particular point?

Comment: @Codexer while that may work, I think going from learning the use of select-cases to learning recursion is a pretty big jump in a beginning programming class...

Comment: Not really... it's just my code is too long because I represent every number to words. 

Recursion? how does it work?

Comment: @soohoonigan. Any bright ideas to make my code clean? my code is so long because I represent every number to words which it takes my time.

Comment: `learning recursion is a pretty big jump`, would you rather write out thousands of cases`? @soohoonigan... I try to help with proper cases in situations, of course he could do a case for every number up to 99999, that may take awhile...

Comment: @Codexer not just 99999 but also - 99999. So, it is really a pain in the ass for me. Tell me how recursion works and use it in the given problem.

Comment: The way I would attack the problem would be to start by doing some conversions of all lengths manually - that is, pick a bunch of numbers, write them down, and then write down their word forms. There will be some patterns; I would then write my code to take advantage of those patterns.

Comment: Write these numbers vertically and then write the corresponding english word next to them. `1  to  20, 25, 90, 99, 100, 201, 211, 999,  1000,  2345, 9999, 10000, 13452, 99999`.  Now study that list.  Do you see a pattern emerge from how the words are formed to represent the digits?  Once you decipher the pattern, you should be able to write the logic to convert the digits to words.

Comment: It's tricky but it can be done. I just wrote a quick function that can do it with 30 Select Case statements, a couple of recursion calls and 29 actual strings to represent all the numbers from 1 to 99999. It also takes splitting the number into its parts: _thousands, hundreds, tens, ones_ and then using the remainder in the recursion calls. I hesitate to post the code though because this is an assignment you're working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with 30 Case Statements and 29 literal word strings. This is not the complete solution, you'll need to add more logic.

These are the distinct words needed to represent the numbers from 1 to 99,999:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
thirteen
fourteen
fifteen
sixteen
seventeen
eighteen
nineteen
twenty
thirty
fourty
fifty
sixty
seventy
eighty
ninety
hundred
thousand
```

`one to nineteen` is needed when input is 1 to 19

`twenty to ninety` is needed when input is 20 to 99

`hundred` is needed when input is 100 to 999

`thousand` is needed when input >= 1000

So for example, if the number is 1384, break it up into parts and recursively call the same function to return the words.

```
    Private Function convertToWords(input As Integer) As String
        Dim words As String = ""

        Select Case input
            Case 1
                words = "one"

            Case Is >= 1000
                Dim thousands As Integer = (input \ 1000) '<= how many 1000's are there?
                Select Case thousands
                    Case Is > 0
                        input = (input Mod 1000) '<= the remainder is the new value which will be used by calling the same function again
                        words &= convertToWords(thousands) & " thousand " & convertToWords(input)
                End Select    
        End Select

        Return words
    End Function
```

There's 1 thousand and the remainder is 384 which becomes the new input and it will be passed into the same function and it then gets split into hundreds the same way.

Once you add the Case Statements for `1 to 19`, `20,30,40...` and `100 to 999`, it will change the 1 to `one thousand` and 3 to `three hundred` and 80 to `eighty` and 4 to `four` as it's recursively calling itself.

Also keep in mind, you don't need a case statement for `84`, you just need one for `80` and one for `4` because you're splitting it up. So if it's `85`, it will use the same `80` case and the `5` case when called recursively.