# convert numbers to words in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is a follow-up concern. I need to convert numbers to words in vb.net using only select case. WE ARE NOT allowed to use functions, if else , loops, subs and arrays. What I did is divide each number places (ones, tens, hundreds, and so on). Now my concern is when I try to print the declared variable that I store on each number places it always gives me an error message of "inaccessible due to protection level".

Can anyone give me a tip on how I will store them and print it once? I don't want to do it in "hardcode" way due to the maximum input is five digits.

So here is the sample of my code:

```
    Select Case input >= 20 And input <= 99
        Case True
            Dim tens As String = Math.Floor(input \ 10)
            Dim ones As String = Math.Floor(input \ 10 Mod 10)
            Dim StrTens As String
            Dim StrOnes As String
            Select Case tens
                Case tens = 1
                    StrTens = "Twenty "
                Case tens = 3
                    StrTens = "Thirty "
            End Select

            Select Case ones
                Case ones = 1
                    StrOnes = "One"
                Case ones = 2
                    StrOnes = "Two"

            End Select

    End Select
    lblOutput.Text = StrTens + StrOnes
```

Comment: Everytime the code indents it creates a new level of *scope*.  `tens`, `ones` etc only exist inside the `Case True` block.  Move them outside it If you need to allow for 5 digits you are going to need hundreds, thousands and tens of thousands too, no?

Comment: @Plutonix not sure on how I will do it. I'm kinda new on vb.net. Can you give me some ideas or atleast portion of code on how I will do it?

Comment: Move all your `Dim` statements to above the `Select Case` statement.

Comment: Didn't you ask this before? Create a function to do it and let it recursively call itself. Then you just need to pass your input to the function and it will return the string. This was a partial solution to get you started here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550911/convert-numbers-to-words-using-only-select-case-in-vb-net/45553615#45553615

Comment: @ChaseRocker Yes!! But the thing is our professor said we are NOT allowed to use functions and recursions :(

Actually, I already finished (thank you for help) this by using functions with the help of youtube and google but I need to follow my professors instructions

Comment: No functions, no if/then statements, no recursion...what kind of programming class is this? He's teaching you to do it the hard way instead of the right way.

Comment: @ChaseRocker that's the way it is. As a student, I just follow my professor's instructions. I'm sorry :(

Comment: I understand. The way he's asking you to do it means you'll have to duplicate the same code in multiple places. That will work of course, but it's a bad habit to pick up when you're learning to program.

Comment: @ChaseRocker It will work but it consumes a lot of time.Anyway, do you have any bright idea on how I will do it? and at least more efficient?

Comment: You said you're not allowed to use functions, subs, if-else, arrays and loopings. But are you allowed to use Goto statement? Goto statement is usually avoided but it can help you to imitate the looping behavior without looping statements.

Comment: @Han GoTo statement is not allowed since I believe it is under of looping...

Comment: You can use Goto statement to jump to anywhere you want. It can substitute looping and if-else. It can imitate a subroutine too.

Comment: Technically, Goto belongs to the jump statements group (goto, return, break, continue in C/C++ or Goto, Return, Exit Do/Exit For/Exit While, Continue in VB.Net).

Comment: There are *functions* such as those provided by libraries to do all this for you and then there are ***functions*** in which you embed code you write to perform the task.  the teacher almost certainly means the former and not the latter.  A key element in digesting requirements is differentiate what they say from what they mean

Comment: @Han so How I will do it since the primary objective is to use Select Case statement?

Comment: You can emulate a subroutine or looping using Goto and labels.

Comment: @Han. Ok, I will try it *fingerscrossed*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Numbers to Words using only SELECT CASE in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550911/convert-numbers-to-words-using-only-select-case-in-vb-net). You asked the same question already, dont ask it again...

Comment: @Codexer. please backread the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. This seems to work. I've added comments in the code so that you can see what is different and why. Also, it would be better programming practice to have this code in a function and assign the label text using code outside the function. Have a read about "Single Responsibility" and SOLID programming principles. Here you go.

```
'this in my example just makes sure that all the
'variables are declared. If you have declared them
'outside this code, you should be able to delete them
'They need to be declared outside of the Select..Case
'statements, otherwise they would only be visible inside
'the Select..Case statements
Dim tens, ones As Integer
Dim strTens As String = ""
Dim strOnes As String = ""
Select Case input >= 20 And input <= 99
    Case True
        'This is a simplified version of your code.
        'Math.floor returns a result that is a Double
        'type, so strictly speaking you should convert it
        'to an integer type
        tens = CInt(Math.Floor(input \ 10))
        'your original calculation wil result in an 
        'incorrect result for example if input=22
        '32 divided by 10 is 3.2. 3.2 mod 10 will
        'be 3.2
        'The method below returns the correct result
        ones = CInt(Math.Floor(input Mod 10))
        Select Case tens
            Case 2
                strTens = "Twenty "
            Case 3
                strTens = "Thirty "
        End Select
        Select Case ones
            Case 1
                strOnes = "One"
            Case 2
                strOnes = "Two"
        End Select
        'Using + to concatenate strings is a bad idea
        'because + will attempt to perform and arithmetic
        'add operation and if either string is not purely
        'digits, I think you will get an "InvalidCastException"
        'when you try to run it. Using &  indicates your
        'intention to concatenate them not add numbers
        test = strTens & " " & strOnes
        'You didn't specify what to do if the number is outside
        'you range of 20-99. This is a poor way of doing that,
        'but simple enough for your needs for now
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Number must be >19 and <100")
            test = ""
    End Select
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful idea and correction @David Wilson. Now I have a bright idea on how I will finish this. :)